# SELinux Policy to Allow NGINX Access to Parallels Shared Folders on Mac

Tags: nginx, centos, parallels, selinux, centos7

I'm trying to keep SELinux enforcing but to allow NGINX to directly access shared OSX folders that are connected via Parallels Desktop.

- Host system: Mac OSX 10.10
- Parallels Desktop: 10
- Running Virtual OS: CentOS 7 (minimal / command line)

I have the the Parallels tools installed and in CentOS I see the shared folder: /media/psf/Shared-Folder

When I set the Nginx server root to that folder I get a 403 Forbidden.  I know it is a configuration parameter that needs editing because if I change SELinux to Permissive, the files are served correctly in NGINX.

When checking how the files are mounted I see this:

```
root root system_u:object_r:removable_t:s0 /media/psf/Shared-Folder/
```

I can see the 'removable_t' context - however - my issue is that I cannot seem to find a way to allow the httpd service to serve files that are mounted as removable storage.

I have tried:

```
chcon -R -t public_content_t /media/psf/Shared_Folder/

chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /media/psf/Development-Projects/
```

and in all cases I get a *"chcon: failed to change context of: '...': Operational not supported"* error.

Checking */usr/sbin/getsebool -a | grep http* I do not see any option to allow httpd to access removable storage mounts.

Last item: I do not believe I can change the way Parallels mounts the shared folders.

**Question:** Is there a way to keep SELinux enforcing but to allow NGINX to directly access shared OSX folders that are connected via Parallels Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use `semanage`.To get it you have to install `policycoreutils-python`.
The same type of question has already been asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597482/configure-selinux-access-so-that-apache-can-access-mounted-directories). Cheers!