# SELinux Permission Denied Python3.3 CentOS 6.5

Tags: selinux

I am having a tough time with this one.  I am trying to get my GIT repo over Apache and I am running into errors that seem to be related to SELinux.  I am new to SELinux.  I need help deciphering the output in the audit log.  I seen the suggestion to set SELinux to permissive mode to capture the errors and then run it though a command to build a SELinux profile for this operation.  I need assistance in constructing the command from the output.  My Apache Server is calling a python CGI script.  Here is the audit log output:

```
    type=AVC msg=audit(1424300724.345:67): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=2306 comm="python3.3" path=2F746D702F666669316F59336968202864656C6574656429 dev=dm-0 ino=266176 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1424300724.345:67): arch=c000003e syscall=9 success=yes exit=140223631540224 a0=0 a1=1000 a2=5 a3=1 items=0 ppid=2303 pid=2306 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=1 comm="python3.3" exe="/usr/local/bin/python3.3" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to SELinux however, I have learned that for CGI scripts, your files need to have their TYPE attribute set to httpd_sys_script_exec_t ~ [see this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7-Beta/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-Types.html)

You can use the semanage fcontext command to set the CGI scripts with the type required. [semanage link](http://linux.die.net/man/8/semanage)

I believe that you would run something like this:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t  "file.py"
```

Please check the manuals for confirmation/clarification  of any of the above.

Regards, Victor.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways i know arround the issue if the first don't work try the second one:

**The first one:** You need to look in the Selinux logs to print all the error related to python:

```
sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep python | grep denied
```

we are going to use `audit2allow` to fix the issue. You need to install `policycoreutils-python` via `yum` if you don't have it.

And running the following command fixed the issue:

```
sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied | audit2allow -M mypython
sudo semodule -i mynginx.pp
```

**The second one** is presented here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597482/configure-selinux-access-so-that-apache-can-access-mounted-directories).

CHEERS!